# cannot able to connect jboss 6.1 to jconsole via remote access

Tags: jboss

I want to connect my jconsole to the jboss 6.1 via remote access and I am using the jdk and jre 1.7 version can anyone tell me how to do it from scratch please.
I am struggling with this for few past days.[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgJJW.png)

[error while connecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgJJW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remote connection cannot be able to established but you can use the below command to manually generate the heap dump file of a particular java process.

Linux command: sudo -u jboss jmap -dump:format=b,file=.bin

: It is the name of the file you want to give the file extension can be either .bin or .hprof .

: It is the process id of the java process to which you want to create a memory heap dump.